# Identity related to Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Can anyone help me how I show the following:

Assume $Y_t-Y_s \sim N(0, \sigma^2 (t-s))$ for all $0 \leq s < t$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a constant $c_n$ (not depending on $s$ and $t$) such that $\mathbb{E} \left[ |Y_t -Y_s|^{2n} \right] = c_n \sigma^{2n} |t-s|^n$ for $\forall s,t \geq 0$.

The question is how I find such a $c_n$.

Comment: Notice that $Y_t - Y_s \stackrel{\text{law}}{=} \sigma\sqrt{t-s} Z$ where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is a standard normal variable. So it follows that $c_n = \mathbb{E}[Z^{2n}]$ is the $(2n)$-th moment of $Z$, which can be computed in many ways. For instance, $n$-fold integration by parts definitely works here. Alternatively, [*Isserlis' theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem) tells that $$ \mathbb{E}[Z^{2n}] = [\text{# of perfect matchings on $\{1,\cdots,2n\}$}] = \frac{1}{2^n}\binom{2n}{n} = (2n-1)!! $$